# MVC sessions with auto-refreshing site

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking into session issues I have, but before I post my other questions I need to clarify something.

When a website is designed with JavaScript code that keeps refreshing the site (say every 5 seconds), I would expect that to be the same as a user clicking on links that reload fresh copies of the page, and further I would expect that to keep the site in session until the end of time.

However the session (ie, my session variables) does time out (I think at the 20 min default, but I'm not sure yet).

What's the expected behavior when a page auto-refreshes? Timeout or no timeout ?

Thank you,
Simon

Comment: It should not depend on auto-refresh or not. How do you handle a user inactive for 20 minutes? Is it a security risk or not?

Comment: The site has information updated live throughout the day, so it's supposed to stay up with the user just looking at it. To answer your Q, I'm am trying to go out of my way to NOT handle user inactive for 20 mins, as the user is always inactive.  No security concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have forms authentications that stores cookies that are get expired in 20 minuts, page refresh doesn't extends the exipration. [Look Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) for possible options, sliding expiration may help.

Comment: The timeout on my form authentication is set to 60 mins, but I don't think this is a form auth timeout issue, I think this is a session State timeout issue.